# what is the best way to check empty cache with MemoryCache Class?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, memorycache, asp.net-caching

I'm using simple `ObjectCache` and `MemoryCache` class to implement cache.

```
public class MemoryCacheManager
    {
        protected ObjectCache Cache
        {
            get
            {
                return MemoryCache.Default;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the value associated with the specified key.
        public virtual T Get<T>(string key)
        {
            return (T)Cache[key];
        }
```

> I want to add method to check empty cache but not based on any key 
>   only wanted to check whether whole cache is empty or not how can I do so ?

Comment: [GetCount()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.objectcache.getcount(v=vs.110).aspx) == 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `GetCount()` method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.getcount(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var cache = MemoryCache.Default;

bool isEmpty = cache.GetCount() == 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [GetCount()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.getcount(v=vs.110).aspx) method to see how many items are in the `MemoryCache`.